# OrderCloud filtering by empty extended properties

Tags: ordercloud

I have extended property `IsDeleted` in `Buyers` entity. And I want to filter `buyers` who don't have this property or have it with `false` value. How can I do that?

Comment: I'd be curious to know the reasoning behind using an xp property to mark a buyer as deleted, as opposed to actually deleting the buyer or setting Buyer.Active to false.

Comment: We have two conditions for Buyers. Inactive and deleted. And we can mark as deleted only inactive Buyers.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: this is supported as of [1.0.72](https://ordercloud-api.github.io/release-notes/ordercloud-api-v1.0.72.html)

> Now, xp filters don’t just look for the specified xp and filter down from there. Instead, a filter of xp.Color=!Blue will return all items with xp.Color where the color isn’t blue, but also any items without xp.Color at all.

---

There is no current way to filter on xp properties that do not exist (though it is on the roadmap). The recommended solution is to make sure all of your Buyers have the xp property of IsDeleted, and then filter on the values where it is false.

```
GET /buyers?xp.IsDeleted=false
```

Comment: as you mention the above feature ( filter on xp properties that do not exist) is in roadmap. could please let me know its complete or still in roadmap.

Comment: @Milind please check out the update posted. This feature became available in March 2018.